# Probability that none of the means are equal?

Tags: anova, t-test

Suppose that I have some number of sample means and their standard errors. How can I work out the probability that *none* of the means are equal?

I know that ANOVA can be used to find the probability that *at least one* mean differs from the rest, but is there a way to do the "opposite" problem?

I suppose I could do a pairwise t-test for every possible combination of pairs and take the highest probability that comes out. But is this a valid way? Is it the only way?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tukey%27s_range_test and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Family-wise_error_rate#Holm.27s_step-down_procedure_.281979.29.  You can also search our site for [Tukey HSD](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=tukey%20hsd)

Comment: The usual ANOVA does not tell you "the probability that at least one mean differs from the rest"; that would require some kind of Bayesian analysis. It sounds like you are misinterpreting a p-value.